# flutter number keyboard doesn't have done button

Tags: keyboard, flutter, textinput

I'm using TextInputType.number in my TextField. But there is not any done or next button inside keyboard.TextInputAction.done isn’t working on number keyboard. What should I do for that ?

Comment: Which version of Flutter are you using? The `textInputAction` property was added fairly recently.

Comment: I’m using last version. TextInputType.number doesn’t support textInputAction. I’m trying to find other solutions.

Comment: have you found the solution? got the same issue too.

Comment: No I didnt find any solution.

Comment: You can use a custom approach, I have just published a story on medium for that. https://medium.com/@webianks/keyboard-done-button-ux-in-flutter-ios-app-3b29ad46bacc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just created a package for add basic actions to the current keyboards .

[image]

You can take a look here :

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Sample code:

```
        import  'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import  'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';

         //...
          FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();
          FocusNode _nodeText2 = FocusNode();
          FocusNode _nodeText3 = FocusNode();
          FocusNode _nodeText4 = FocusNode();
          FocusNode _nodeText5 = FocusNode();

         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Keyboard Actions Sample"),
              ),
              body: FormKeyboardActions(
                keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL, //optional
                keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey, //optional
                nextFocus: true, //optional
                actions: [
                  KeyboardAction(
                    focusNode: _nodeText1,
                  ),
                  KeyboardAction(
                    focusNode: _nodeText2,
                    closeWidget: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  KeyboardAction(
                    focusNode: _nodeText3,
                    onTapAction: () {
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              content: Text("Custom Action"),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                FlatButton(
                                  child: Text("OK"),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  ),
                  KeyboardAction(
                    focusNode: _nodeText4,
                    displayCloseWidget: false,
                  ),
                  KeyboardAction(
                    focusNode: _nodeText5,
                    closeWidget: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Text("CLOSE"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          focusNode: _nodeText1,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Input Number",
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          focusNode: _nodeText2,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Input Text with Custom Close Widget",
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          focusNode: _nodeText3,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Input Number with Custom Action",
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          focusNode: _nodeText4,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Input Text without Close Widget",
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          focusNode: _nodeText5,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Input Number with Custom Close Widget",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Comment: How does this package interact with Scaffold's resizeToAvoidBottomInset?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a third-party package, you can also set the [onTapOutside](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onTapOutside.html) method in your TextField.

```
Center(                                     
  child: Padding(                           
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),    
    child: TextField(                       
      onTapOutside: (event) {               
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();   
      },                                    
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,   
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(    
        hintText: 'Enter a zip code',       
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),       
      ),                                     
    ),                                       
  ),
```

This code will unfocus the TextField if the user taps outside of it (works on mobile and web platforms).

Comment: This is perfect